# Notebook stuck on "Initializing" when using GPU backend

Tags: google-colaboratory

I frequently get stuck with the runtime status "Initializing" when opening Google Colab notebooks using GPUs.

Are other people having this problem? Is it from a shortage of GPUs in the runtime cluster? Has anyone found a better solution than just coming back later?

Answer (score 22):

This helped me: click on 'Runtime' tab, click on 'Restart runtime...'

Comment: Worked for me too. Thanks.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It really helped me.

Comment: Works on CPU backend as well

Comment: Worked for me using GCP cloud instance

Answer (score 1):

As of now, I think best way to over-ride this problem. is by switching between gpu runtime. Forcing it to look for a free instance.

[Click on the 'Runtime' tab. Click on 'Change runtime type'. Under hardware accelerator select 'GPU']

Comment: Can you pleas provide instructions how to switch?

Comment: Click on the 'Runtime' tab. Click on 'Change runtime type'. Under hardware accelerator select 'GPU'

Comment: Hello! I tried this right now a couple of times, and I'm still stuck on "Initializing". My suspicion is there is a global resource shortage, but it's hard to verify.

Comment: You can verify that, using a vpn.

Comment: changing runtime helped me when restart instance didn't work